# IPW Weights Are "1" For Treated Units

Tags: r, causality, propensity-scores

I am in the process of setting up my analysis using IPW with the R package `WeightIt`. My issue is that my weights seem off from the examples and reading materials I have reviewed in preparation for this analysis. In particular, for all treated units, the weights generated from IPW are equal to "1". Below is the syntax for the analysis:

```
# Generate the Weights
pko_weights <- weightit(pko ~ lnatres + lgdppc + lpop + lmilper,
                        data = merged,
                        estimand = "ATT",
                        method = "ps")

# Merge the Weights Into the Data Set
merged <- merged %>%
  mutate(ipw = pko_weights$weights)
```

At every point where a unit is treated, the `ipw` weight = 1 and I am trying to figure out why this is the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Treated units' weights are 1 by design for ATT. You can work out the math to see that for ATT you use inverse _odds_ weighting, rather than inverse _probability_ weighting: You basically multiply the weights by $p$ so the weight for the treated ends up being $\frac{p}{p}=1$ and $p\cdot \frac{1}{1-p}$ for the untreated. Intuitively, since you're looking for the effect on the treated - you don't change their distribution (i.e., keep the samples as they are), and only change the distribution of the untreated units to become more similar to the treated units distribution.

Comment: @ehudk That makes a lot of sense and was my suspicion after I posted this. I appreciate it.